# Can't find oss-parent-7.jar

Tags: java

```
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
    Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
    Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom (5 KB at 4.2 KB/sec)
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Jest Apache HC Jar 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] The POM for io.searchbox:jest-common:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 6.504s
    [INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 07 14:50:25 CST 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/119M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jest: Could not resolve dependencies for project io.searchbox:jest:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find io.searchbox:jest-common:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: Sorry this is useless, some context would be helpful

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: In my .m2 floder not find jar,only pom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [jest readme on github](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest), you need to add the sonatype maven repository:

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
   <id>sonatype</id>
   <name>Sonatype Groups</name>
   <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>
```

And then the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively, build the repository yourself and [install it locally](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=io.searchbox -DartifactId=jest -Dversion=0.1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

Forget the repository if you're installing it locally, but include the dependency.