# Cannot find parent: org.sonatype, atmosphere-project

Tags: java, maven

Maven back this error

> Reason: Cannot find parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent for project: org.atmosphere:atmosphere-project:pom:0.8.4 for project org.atmosphere:atmosphere-project:pom:0.8.4

my pom file is

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
                <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <type>bundle</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
                <artifactId>atmosphere-project</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <type>bundle</type>
            </dependency>


<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->
```

Comment: It could be because the artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent could be missing in your central repository , incase  you are using your companies repo, rather than the public ones? Can you check which repository is configured in your maven settings file?

Comment: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 and next text from settings file I had added into question.

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243566/cant-find-oss-parent-7-jar